# How to migrate from doctrine MongoDB to REST API in symfony2?

Tags: mongodb, rest, symfony, doctrine-orm

Now I have project on Symfony2, in which was used DoctrineMongoDBBundle. I have a few documents with mappings and few controllers/views which working with this documents.

And I need to migrate my application from using mongodb to use our internal REST API. It is desirable to change existing code as little as possible.

Perfect solution - to do something with doctrine, and result of this changes is that doctrine based of existing documents worked as it is, exclude execute CRUD operations. It must not put data into DB, but make requests to REST API. But I have no idea how to do it =) Can someone help me find solutions? For the most detailed answers I will be especially grateful.

Comment: Doens't MongDB a database? and that any REST API needs a database? What migration are you meaning?

Comment: @whiteletters-in-blankpapers Perhaps I poorly explained. Sorry for this. Now I have application, which use MongoDB as storage of data. But we have internal REST API. And this API work with same DB. And my task is to teach current application to store data using API, without direct connection to DB. But there is a lot of code that is tied to work with DoctrineMongoDBBundle. So I need something, that teach DoctrineMongoDBBundle select/write data not from/into mongo, but select/write data via requests to API. I hope that it will be easier to understand what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a bad question. Turning SQL queries into REST queries opens the ability to refactor big monoliths by sending the data to an external single source of truth (maybe a message broker) without changing any line of code, but a few configurations. Have a look at the Doctrine Rest Driver which is exactly what you are looking for:

https://github.com/CircleOfNice/DoctrineRestDriver

You just need to change the Doctrine config and all your SQL queries will be sent to the API instead.